# WRO4J: Spring mapping WRO4J resources facing issue

Tags: wro4j

We are using WRO4J for our application to generate optimized web resources. I need to work this with spring mvc:resources. Now if do the configuration its failing to load the resources.

My configuration given below.

here /img/, /admin/img/ are physical location in web resources and its mapping proper to the logical version url.

But /wro/ is a logical location configured based on WRO4J requirement. There is any way to map the mvc:resources to map the logical location like this.

If you guys have any thoughts please share here.

Thank u so much!

-Geek-

Answer (score 0):

The default mapping used by wro4j `/wro/*` is not a requirement. You can map the WroFilter to any suitable location, example: `*.js` or `*.css`. When it is mapped to something like `*.js`, it will handle all requests having js extension and in case it cannot handle it, the filter will chain the request processing.

Comment: I have created groups, for css and js to merge the css and js files (to avoid multiple requests), the issue am facing here is spring will be looking for the physical location /wro/ in the webapp. but wro4j will create the file on the fly based on the request (using different group i have defined)